# Text extraction between identical lines

Tags: perl, shell, grep

I need to extract lines of text between lines and populate this into an excel file. There is variability between number of line but they are starting with 
Comment for record "idno"...string of other text

```
__DATA__ (This is what my .txt file looks like)
Comment for the record "id1"
Attempt1 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 1

Comment for the record "id2"
Attempt1 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 1
Attempt2 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 2

Comment for the record "id3"
Attempt1 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 1
Attempt2 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 2
Attempt3 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 3
Attempt4 made on [time] outcome [outcome]
note 4
```

Want this displayed as

```
id1     Attempt1   Note1 [outcome]
id2     Attempt1   Note1 [outcome]
id2     Attempt2   Note2 [outcome]
id3     Attempt1   Note1 [outcome]
id3     Attempt2   Note2 [outcome]
id3     Attempt3   Note3 [outcome]
id3     Attempt4   Note4 [outcome]
```

The outcome value would be changing and would be 2-3 digit numeric code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked through this site for last day or 2 but due to my limited experience I wasn't able to find something relevant and me being fairly new perl and shell thought it would be better to post it as a question.

Kind Regard,
Ace

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk (for the regex capturing groups)

```
gawk '
    /^$/ {next}
    match($0, /Comment for the record "([^"]*)/, a) {id = a[1]; next}
    match($0, /(.+) made on .* outcome (.+)/, a) {att = a[1]; out = a[2]; next}
    {printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", id, att, $0, out)}
'
```

or, translating to Perl:

```
perl -lne '
    chomp;
    next if /^$/;
    if (/Comment for the record "([^"]*)/) {$id = $1; next;}
    if (/(.+) made on .* outcome (.+)/) {$att = $1; $out = $2; next;}
    print join("\t", $id, $att, $_, $out);
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data aligns well with a **paragraph-oriented parsing strategy**. Because your specification is vague, it's difficult to know exactly what regular expressions are needed, but this should illustrate the general approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Paragraph mode: read the input file a paragraph/block at a time.
local $/ = "";

while (my $block = <>){
    # Convert the block to lines.
    my @lines = grep /\S/, split("\n", $block);

    # Parse the text, capturing needing items from @lines as we consume it.
    # Note also the technique of assigning regex captures directly to variables.
    my ($id) = shift(@lines) =~ /"(.+)"/;
    while (@lines){
        my ($attempt, $outcome) = shift(@lines) =~ /(Attempt\d+).+outcome (\d+)/;
        my $note = shift @lines;
        print join("\t", $id, $attempt, $note, $outcome), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `$/ = "\n\n"` means exactly two newlines, whereas the recommended setting of `$/ = ""` means **two or more newlines,** so that it isn’t sensitive to how many blank lines you have and each record always begins with real data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you search something like this. It print CSV which can be opened by excel

```
use strict;

local $/;

block(/(id\d+)/,$_) for split /\n\n/, <DATA>;

sub block {
  my ($id,$block) = @_;

  $block =~ s/.*?(?=Attempt)//s;

  print join(',', $id, /(Attempt\d+)/, /([^\n]+)$/, /outcome (\d+)/)."\n"
    for split /(?=Attempt)/, $block
  ;
}
```

Comment: CPAN also has a simple Excel module which might be useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks pretty straight forward:

- You look for a line that starts with `Comment`. This will contain your ID.
- Once you have an ID, you'll have an Attempt line which is followed by a note line. Read the attempt and the line after which will contain the note.
- When you get to the next comment, you rinse and repeat.

We have a particular structure: Each ID will have an array of *attempts*. Each attempt will contain a *outcome* and a *note*.

I'm going to use object oriented Perl here. I'll put all of the record ids into a *list* called `@dataList`, each item in this list is a type `Id`.

Each type `Id` will consist of an array of *Attempts* and each *Attempt* will have an *Id*, *Time*, *Outcome*, and *Note*.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

########################################################################
# READ IN AND PARSE YOUR DATA
#

my @dataList;

my $record;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^Comment for the record "(.*)"/) {
        my $id = $1;
        $record = Id->new($id);
        push @dataList, $record;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^(\S+)\s+made on\s(\S+)\soutcome\s(.*)/) {
        my $attemptId = $1;
        my $time = $2;
        my $outcome = $3;

        # Next line is the note

        chomp (my $note = <DATA>);
        my $attempt = Attempt->new($attemptId, $time, $outcome, $note);
        $record->PushAttempt($attempt);
    }
}

foreach my $id (@dataList) {
    foreach my $attempt ($id->Attempt) {
        print $id->Id . "\t";
        print $attempt->Id . "\t";
        print $attempt->Note . "\t";
        print $attempt->Outcome . "\n";
    }
}
#
########################################################################


########################################################################
# PACKAGE Id;
#
package Id;
use Carp;

sub new {
    my $class       = shift;
    my $id  = shift;

    my $self = {};

    bless $self, $class;

    $self->Id($id);

    return $self;
}

sub Id {
    my $self = shift;
    my $id   = shift;

    if (defined $id) {
        $self->{ID} = $id;
    }

    return $self->{ID};
}

sub PushAttempt {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $attempt = shift;

    if (not defined $attempt) {
        croak qq(Missing Attempt in call to Id->PushAttempt);
    }
    if (not exists ${$self}{ATTEMPT}) {
        $self->{ATTEMPT} = [];
    }
    push @{$self->{ATTEMPT}}, $attempt;

    return $attempt;
}

sub PopAttempt {
    my $self = shift;

    return pop @{$self->{ATTEMPT}};
}

sub Attempt {
    my $self = shift;
    return @{$self->{ATTEMPT}};
}


#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# PACKAGE Attempt
#
package Attempt;

sub new {
    my $class       = shift;
    my $id  = shift;
    my $time        = shift;
    my $note        = shift;
    my $outcome = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;

    $self->Id($id);
    $self->Time($time);
    $self->Note($note);
    $self->Outcome($outcome);

    return $self;
}

sub Id {
    my $self = shift;
    my $id   = shift;


    if (defined $id) {
        $self->{ID} = $id;
    }

    return $self->{ID};
}

sub Time {
    my $self = shift;
    my $time = shift;

    if (defined $time) {
        $self->{TIME} = $time;
    }

    return $self->{TIME};
}

sub Note {
    my $self = shift;
    my $note = shift;

    if (defined $note) {
        $self->{NOTE} = $note;
    }

    return $self->{NOTE};
}

sub Outcome {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $outcome = shift;

    if (defined $outcome) {
        $self->{OUTCOME} = $outcome;
    }

    return $self->{OUTCOME};
}
#
########################################################################

package main;

__DATA__
Comment for the record "id1"
Attempt1 made on [time] outcome [outcome11]
note 11

Comment for the record "id2"
Attempt21 made on [time] outcome [outcome21]
note 21
Attempt22 made on [time] outcome [outcome22]
note 22

Comment for the record "id3"
Attempt31 made on [time] outcome [outcome31]
note 31
Attempt32 made on [time] outcome [outcome32]
note 32
Attempt33 made on [time] outcome [outcome33]
note 33
Attempt34 made on [time] outcome [outcome34]
note 34
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very reliable, but here's a fun attempt with `sed`

```
sed -r -n 's/Comment for the record "([^"]+)"$/\1/;tgo;bnormal;:go {h;n;};:normal /^Attempt[0-9]/{s/(.+) made on .* outcome (.+)$/\1 \2/;G;s/\n/ /;s/(.+) (.+) (.+)/\3\t\1\t\2/;N;s/\t([^\t]+)\n(.+)/\t\2\t\1/;p;d;}' data.txt
```

Note: GNU sed only. Portability is simple to achieve if needed.

Answer (score 0):

awk oneliner based on your example.

```
kent$  awk 'NF==5{gsub(/\"/,"",$5);id=$5;next;} /^Attempt/{n=$1;gsub(/Attempt/,"Note",n);print id,$1,n,$6}' input                      
id1 Attempt1 Note1 [outcome]
id2 Attempt1 Note1 [outcome]
id2 Attempt2 Note2 [outcome]
id3 Attempt1 Note1 [outcome]
id3 Attempt2 Note2 [outcome]
id3 Attempt3 Note3 [outcome]
id3 Attempt4 Note4 [outcome]
```